# If map/filter/reduce is used on data array for Flatlist, everytime when render is called all list item will be redraw?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm curious if map/filter/reduce would be harmful to performance.

Let's say I have a Flatlist(ListView) and its data is a result of map/filter of an array.

When render is called by other state's changed and array values are not changed. 
Then, AFAIK, map/filter create a new object even though values in array are not changed.

At that time, the Flatlist(ListView) actually redraw the whole list? or render is called and nothing happens to ListView?

I hope it's wise enough so it won't redraw ListView.

Comment: react use keys in all list render , to avoid re render unchanged item , if u set key , dont worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatList uses a key value from each data object (see `keyExtractor` property) to determine if the objects in the same order and a shallow equal to determine if render is needed.

See also the `extraData` property as a way of controlling render.

Filter gives a new array with objects with the same identity.  Map gives a new array with objects with the same or different identity (depending on what the map function returns).

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks. Well, then what happen if key and value are not changed but the identity is changed somehow by complicated map?

Comment: That's not identity.  With objects, they are passed by reference, not by value.  You can change the value of an objects property without changing its identity.  The function passed to map can return the same object, the same object identity after modification, or a new object, depending on how its implemented.  All map guarantees is that the array is not the same array as the one being mapped. See the docs on `extraData` which helps control item render.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover shallow equality checks and extraData prop in FlatList

Comment: I got it. I meant the case when creating a new object from that map and return it. The key and value are not changed but its identity is changed, then it triggers redraw at every render() called? Except that, your answer gave me correct answer I think. According to your answer, it will trigger the redraw. right? Thanks!